# How do I fix this error in my OpenCV paint application?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to create a OpenCV-Python application where I have a colour selector in one window where it will display the colour and in the other window display the image where I can draw on it,

```
  File "y:/OpenCV Tutorial/paint_program.py", line 41, in <module>
    wind1[:] = 0
NameError: name 'wind1' is not defined
```

```
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

img = cv2.imread('assets/logo.png')
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('wind1', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.createTrackbar('R','wind1',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('G','wind1',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('B','wind1',0,255,nothing)

switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
cv2.createTrackbar(switch, 'wind1',0,1,nothing)

drawing = False
mode = True
ix,iy = -1,-1

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),10,(b,g,r),-1)

cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

    r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('R','wind1')
    g = cv2.getTrackbarPos('G','wind1')
    b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('B','wind1')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(switch,'wind1')

    if s == 0:
        wind1[:] = 0
    else:
        wind1[:] = [b,g,r]

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the following `ìf`-`else` block

```py
if s == 0:
    wind1[:] = 0
else:
     wind1[:] = [b,g,r]
```

The error and I ask the same question? What is `wind1`?

Appearantly you want to store the `b`, `g`, `r` values.

One way to fix is initializing `wind1`.

```py
wind1 = []

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    .
    .
    .
```

The second issue is, since we declare `wind1` as a list. Now we have to set the values appropriately.

```py
if s == 0:
    wind1[:] = [0, 0, 0]
else:
    wind1[:] = [b, g, r]
```

or

```py
wind1[:] = [0, 0, 0] if s == 0 else [b, g, r]
```

The problem should be solved.

Code:

```py
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

img = cv2.imread('0.jpg')
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('wind1', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.createTrackbar('R','wind1',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('G','wind1',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('B','wind1',0,255,nothing)

switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
cv2.createTrackbar(switch, 'wind1',0,1,nothing)

drawing = False
mode = True
ix,iy = -1,-1

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),10,(b,g,r),-1)

cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

wind1 = []

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

    r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('R','wind1')
    g = cv2.getTrackbarPos('G','wind1')
    b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('B','wind1')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(switch,'wind1')

    wind1[:] = [0, 0, 0] if s == 0 else [b, g, r]

print(wind1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am also having a problem where I want the colour displayed in the wind1 window. https://prnt.sc/10u9ho3

Comment: But I tried the code, and it works: https://prnt.sc/10u9nez

Comment: The colour from the trackbars should be displayed below the trackbars but it is not being displayed.

Comment: Glad if I could help